# puppeteer chromium url redirects to malware

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a node.js (v12.17.0) npm (6.14.4) project I am running on my Windows 10 command prompt. It is using puppeteer ("puppeteer": "^5.3.1",) to go to a url and get info.

My puppeteer code runs this to go to the page:

```
let targetURL = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Small-Large-Dogs-Muzzle-Anti-Stop-Bite-Barking-Chewing-Mesh-Mask-Training-S-XXL/449423974";
                await page.goto(targetURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
```

And my puppeteer is running a chromium exe I just downloaded, I specify it's locating when I start puppeteer:

```
 var options = {
        executablePath: "C:\\Users\\marti\\Downloads\\chrome-win-new\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe",
```

So when puppeteer stars and goes to that URL, it loads the walmart page at first and seems fine, then a couple of seconds later the page looks like this:

[image]

I ran windows defender and malware antibytes to double check if i had a virus, I checked and if i open chromium without puppeteer it doesnt redirect, only seems to happen in my node js program when I run it.

I tried using  a different url (https://www.petcarerx.com/chicken-soup-for-the-soul-bacon-and-cheese-crunchy-bites-dog-treats/32928?sku=50857#50857) and it did not redirect, does anyone know how i can fix this for my Walmart url?

Comment: Have you tried to use the default browser that comes with the puppeteer package?

Comment: yes, i just tried that by removing my line specifying the executable path but the same issue with redirecting to the text page still happens

Comment: try add             `await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("body")', { 60000 });`